# React-Redux useSelector with a custom equalityFn not updating the oldVal while the newVal is the new state. OldVal is same as the initial state always

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a state which is an array of objects and I am trying to get those values in a component using `useSelector`. I am trying to add an equalityFn to avoid getting values/re-render the page unnecessarily. When I dispatch an action, the store is updated correctly and I can see it and the newVal param gets the new state. However, for some reason, the oldval is always the initial state of that reducer. I was expecting the previous state value not the initial state.

```
const liabilities = useSelector((state: any) => state.liabilities, {
    equalityFn: (oldVal, newVal) => {
      console.log("oldVal is always the initial state");
      console.log("newVal is always the updated state");
      // Some conditions to check the difference between old and new Vals.
      if (
        oldVal.some(
          (ol: ILiabilities) =>
            ol.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
        ) &&
        !newVal.some(
          (nl: ILiabilities) =>
            nl.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
        )
      ) {
        // Remove
        console.log("Remove");
      } else if (
        !oldVal.some(
          (ol: ILiabilities) =>
            ol.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
        ) &&
        newVal.some(
          (nl: ILiabilities) =>
            nl.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
        )
      ) {
        // Add
        debugger;
        console.log("Add");
      } else if (
        oldVal.some(
          (ol: ILiabilities) =>
            ol.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
        ) &&
        newVal.some(
          (nl: ILiabilities) =>
            nl.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
        )
      ) {
        // Update
        console.log("Update");
      }
      // For now
      return true;
    },
  });
```

I am sure I am not mutating the state. I am also using the `reduxImmutableStateInvariant` to avoid mutation at development.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  preloadedState,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? [thunk as ThunkMiddleware, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()]
        : [thunk as ThunkMiddleware]
    ),
});
```

Adding items to the state looks like,[a portion of it]

```
case types.ADD_LIABILITIES: {
      switch (action.liabilitiesType) {
        case LiabilitiesTypeEnum.probate:
          return [
            ...state,
            {
              ...defaultLiabilities,
              liabilitiesType: LiabilitiesTypeEnum.lastExpenses,
            },
          ]; and so on...
```

When I add a liability the useSelector is now triggered with oldVal same as the initial value always and newVal is the updated state. No point in comparing both as the oldVal remains the same for some reason. Any idea? I tried the same EqualityFn on a simple object value in state and oldVal and newVal behaved as expected. I suspect it has something to do when the state is an array in store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue you see is because your equality function always returns true regardless of the old/new values, so effectively there is never an "old" value to "cache" for comparison the next time an equality check is needed.

I was able to reproduce the behavior you describe using your equality function, and I was able to resolve the issue by returning `false`, e.g. a boolean value representing equality, for all the cases you have checking the `state.liabilities` arrays for the "charitableGifts" value.

```js
const liabilities = useSelector((state: any) => state.liabilities, {
  equalityFn: (oldVal, newVal) => {
    // Some conditions to check the difference between old and new Vals.
    if (
      oldVal.some(
        (ol: ILiabilities) =>
          ol.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
      ) &&
      !newVal.some(
        (nl: ILiabilities) =>
          nl.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
      )
    ) {
      // Remove
      return false; // <-- return boolean!!
    } else if (
      !oldVal.some(
        (ol: ILiabilities) =>
          ol.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
      ) &&
      newVal.some(
        (nl: ILiabilities) =>
          nl.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
      )
    ) {
      // Add
      return false; // <-- return boolean!!
    } else if (
      oldVal.some(
        (ol: ILiabilities) =>
          ol.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
      ) &&
      newVal.some(
        (nl: ILiabilities) =>
          nl.liabilitiesType === LiabilitiesTypeEnum.charitableGifts
      )
    ) {
      // Update
      return false; // <-- return boolean!!
    }
    // For now
    return true;
  },
});
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-redux-useselector-with-a-custom-equalityfn-not-updating-the-oldval-while-t]

Comment: Wow. I had added `return false` as needed but didn't check with a matching condition. It works as expected with `return false;`.  Thanks for explaining how it works.